# Getting responseText using g:formRemote with Grails

Tags: ajax, grails

I am trying to access the responseText on a failure ajax call using formRemote

```
<g:remoteLink controller="answer" action="delete" id="${answer.id}"  update="questions" onFailure="handleError(response)" onComplete="assingActionTestElems()"></g:remoteLink>
```

But response is not defined, getting this error in FireBug

```
ReferenceError: response is not defined
```

This is one of my multiple ajax handling error in the controller

```
 render(status: 500, text: message(code: 'edition.answer.delete.pending'))
```

¿How can I access to the text message?

Comment: how about on your IDE, arent you getting any error?

Comment: On the IDE ? I throw an 500 http error, no other errors have happened. Only in firebug.

Comment: how about https://gist.github.com/aeischeid/4152409#file-errorcontroller-groovy-L12 trying json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It´s easy but not documented. There are 3 fields implicited when a error is thrown, and this is the method to access to them:

```
onFailure="handleError(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown)"

   var handleError = function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
       alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
   }
```

You can use just one or all, as needed!